# jquery cycle plugin true crossfade transition

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

Is there a way to set up cycle plugin with a crossfade that does not show a background colour flash between images?

I'd like one image to fade on top of another, instead of both fading at the same time.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here you can find http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the cycle plugin - hence I mentioned it in the title and my question. This is the one I've been using to date, but I now have a requirement to fade the images and cycle's fade is not working as I'd like it to. The first image fades out, revealing the background colour, while the next one fades in. I'd like only the 2nd slide to fade in so that the background is never seen. So, can I adjust the behaviour of the fade?

Comment: can you provide me your code...so that i can work with it and findout the soln....

Comment: Anish - apologies - I didn't spot the fact that you could customise your own transitions. Should be possible using animIn/animOut with opacity rather than the standard fade parameter.